# How to add Office365 custom domain to Windows Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, active-directory, office365, azure-active-directory

I have an Windows Azure Subscription when the administrator has a Microsoft Account.
This account has a Default active directory and I need to configure my Office365 domain to authenticate my applications with corporate accounts.

I cant remove the default directory.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The management portal will not let you do what you are asking. It will not let you associate your Azure account with an existing Windows Azure Active Directory (WAAD) instance, and manage it through the Azure portal. You can, however, still use your Office365 instance of WAAD to as an identity provider through Azure Access Control Service (ACS). For a good starting place on using ACS for adding claims based authentication to your web application look [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/access-control/). For instructions on how to provision a WAAD tenant as an IdP for ACS look [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2012/11/07/PROVISIONING-A-DIRECTORY-TENANT-AS-AN-IDENTITY-PROVIDER-IN-AN-ACS-NAMESPACE/).